# Как правильно упаковать данные в пакет minecraft? (netty)

Tags: java, minecraft, netty

Пытаюсь сделать пакет для отправки сообщения в чат. Уже есть CHandshakePacket и CLoginStartPacket. Они оба работают и передают нужные данные. А при отправке CChatMessagePacket на сервер, вылезает вот это:
`lost connection: Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 14`

CChatMessagePacket:

```
public class CChatMessagePacket extends Packet {

    public String message;
    public GameProfile gp;

    public CChatMessagePacket(String message, GameProfile gp) {
        this.message = message;
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ByteBuf buf) {
        //
        PacketUtils.writeString(this.message, buf);
        buf.writeByte(0);
        PacketUtils.writeUniqueId(GameProfile.getOfflineUUID(gp.getName()), buf);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getWrappedPacket() {
        ByteBuf allocated = Unpooled.buffer();
        allocated.writeByte(0x0E);//айди пакета
        this.write(allocated);//запись данных

        ByteBuf wrapped = Unpooled.buffer();
        PacketUtils.writeVarInt(allocated.readableBytes(), wrapped);
        wrapped.writeBytes(allocated);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[wrapped.readableBytes()];

        wrapped.getBytes(0, bytes);
        wrapped.release();
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

Вот еще CHandshakePacket для примера:

```
public class CHandshakePacket extends Packet {
   public int protocolVersion;
   public String host;
   public int port;
   public int requestedProtocol;
   public CHandshakePacket(int protocolVersion, String host, int port, int requestedProtocol) {
      this.protocolVersion = protocolVersion;
      this.host = host;
      this.port = port;
      this.requestedProtocol = requestedProtocol;
   }
   @Override
   public void write(final ByteBuf buf) {
      PacketUtils.writeVarInt(this.protocolVersion, buf);
      PacketUtils.writeString(this.host, buf);
      buf.writeShort(this.port);
      PacketUtils.writeVarInt(this.requestedProtocol, buf);
   }
   @Override
   public byte[] getWrappedPacket() {
      ByteBuf allocated = Unpooled.buffer();
      allocated.writeByte(0x00);
      this.write(allocated);
      ByteBuf wrapped = Unpooled.buffer();
      PacketUtils.writeVarInt(allocated.readableBytes(), wrapped);
      wrapped.writeBytes(allocated);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[wrapped.readableBytes()];
      wrapped.getBytes(0, bytes);
      wrapped.release();
      return bytes;
   }

}
```

Есть предположения, что я делаю не так и как это исправить?